# Mobile Angular Ui toggle not working

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to use mobile angular ui toggle and toggleable to make a side navigation.

my navigation div looks like this:

```
<div toggleable id="sidemenu" active-class="show" class="hidden">BLA BLA</div>
```

I tried using a simple a tag to make it appear / disappear:

```
<a toggle="toggle" target="sidemenu" active-class="active" href>Side Menu</a>
```

I have included mobile angular ui file and in my app configuration. still, it does not work.

my app initialization:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.controllers','myApp.directives', 'mobile-angular-ui', 'luegg.directives', 'ngRoute', 'ngTouch', 'ngAnimate','wu.masonry']);
```

any suggestions what's the problem?

Comment: Please link all needed context. I don't see any `toggle` or `toggleable` in [Mobile Angular UI](http://mobileangularui.com/docs/#modules).

Comment: seems like they updated to version 1.2, but just now they updated their docs... working now.. thanks :)

Comment: I'd suggest removing the question then, to avoid attracting more people to that shining bounty :)

Comment: You can achieve toggle with native angularjs using `ng-class` and `ng-click`. I do not see the reason that you must use another module to acheive your goal, which makes your code more complex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

seems like the manuals were not up to date.
solved :)